# Why can't spacecraft slow down before entering Earth's atmosphere?

Tags: reentry

Given the dangers of the massive heat generated during re-entry, why can't spacecraft simply slow down using thrusters (or whatever) and just come in gently?

Comment: The original booster gave the spacecraft its orbital velocity.  Wouldn't you need an identical booster to remove that same velocity?

Answer (score 3):

Because [propellant is extremely costly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) in orbit (as of now). As long as you have to bring up every gram from earths gravity well, you **want** your tanks to be as empty as possible before re-entry. Aerobraking is currently the only way to get rid of speed without relying on costly propellant.

That being said, things might change if propellant would already exist in-orbit and was relatively cheap to acquire. In that case it might be more sensible to re-fuel (re-propell?) before descent.

Comment: To illustrate how expensive it is to boost propellant to space:  Suppose you developed a rocket that could burn money with a performance similar to current space-stable propellants.  If NASA could go to the Bank of Space and withdraw piles of dollar bills to stuff in the engine they would do so--it would be cheaper than bringing fuel up from Earth.